# JavaScript group a series of objs

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, object, reduce

I have the following code, where I have a set of obj `b` is where the way to group them are defined in `a` by `elements`.

I'm having some doubts about how to do it.
For example, is it correct to scroll `a` or `b`?

Can you give me a hand?

```
const a = [{
    _id: 0,
    elements: ['aasa', 'cccx', 'zzzx', 'sd']
  },
  {
    _id: 1,
    elements: ['bb', 'xx']
  }
];

const b = [{
    _id: 'aasa',
    info: "sssas"
  },
  {
    _id: 'bb'
  },
  {
    _id: 'zzzx',
    info: "ssss"
  },
  {
    _id: 'cccx',
    info: "sss"
  },
  {
    _id: 'xx'
  }
];

// result
[
  [{
      _id: 'aasa',
      info: "sssas"
    },
    {
      _id: 'zzzx',
      info: "ssss"
    },
    {
      _id: 'cccx',
      info: "sss"
    }
  ],
  [{
      _id: 'bb'
    },
    {
      _id: 'xx'
    }
  ]
];

c = a.map(el => el.elements)


const p = b
  //.map(el => el.elements)
  .reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    //if
    prev.push(curr);
    return prev;
  }, []);

//console.log("End",p)
```

Comment: You can do it in one line: `const c = a.map(item => b.filter(obj => item.elements.includes(obj._id)));`

Comment: In your result, the object with id `cccx` comes last, but in `elements` the id `cccx` comes before `zzzx`, is there a reason why the order is swapped or was this done unintentionally?

Comment: @NickParsons: For what it needs me to use it for, sorting is influential.
But I thought that the data coming to me from the backend is not sorted, for example order that is inside elements, it might not match has as I have all objs.

Being an idea it was to use b for objects, I kept ordering that I had objects in b.
I do not know if I have explained very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first change `b` to be a lookup object (here I have used a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)), where each id is a key that points to the object itself:

```js
// Transform `b` into a Map of the form:
Map {
  'aasa' => {
    _id: 'aasa',
    info: "sssas"
  },
  'bb' => {
    _id: 'bb'
  }
  // ... etc ...
}
```

Then, for each object in `a`, you can map over the `elements` array, and use the id from that object as a key in the lookup object to obtain the associated object with that id. Before you perform a map, you can first filter any keys (ie: ids) that don't exist in the lookup table by using `.has` on the Map:

```js
const a = [{ _id: 0, elements: ['aasa', 'cccx', 'zzzx', 'sd'] }, { _id: 1, elements: ['bb', 'xx'] } ];
const b = [{ _id: 'aasa', info: "sssas" }, { _id: 'bb' }, { _id: 'zzzx', info: "ssss" }, { _id: 'cccx', info: "sss" }, { _id: 'xx' } ];

const lut = new Map(b.map(obj => [obj._id, obj]));
const res = a.map(({elements}) => elements.filter(key => lut.has(key)).map(key => lut.get(key)));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: May I ask you why you propose to create a lookup object rather than simply do: `const c = a.map(item => b.filter(obj => item.elements.includes(obj._id)));` (or something similar)?

Comment: @secan for larger data sets, using a Map can make this more efficient (time complexity for a `map()` then `filter()` with an `.includes()` would be O(|a| * |b| * |elements|), whereas the time complexity for the above approach is O(|b| + |a| * |elements|)

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
const c = a.map(el1 => {
   return b.filter(el2 => {
      return el1.elements.includes(el2._id)
   })
});
```